# Is it possible to unlock an iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3 via software?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, unlock

I recently bought a cheap iPhone 4S, I know it's an old device but I wanna gift it to my mom so she can use it as what it is: a phone. The iPhone 4S is currently running iOS 6.1.3, but the device is blocked so I can't use it as a phone with my actual (and unique carrier, I'm from Cuba). The device seems to only work on Verizon network.

I was researching and there is (or was?) 3 main methods to unlock a phone:

1. Paying a company to unlock it via IMEI (I can't do it, because I'm in Cuba and have no access to any kind of card or online methods to pay)
2. Going to the previous/actual carrier and ask them to unlock it (My actual, and unique, carrier don't do this kind of things, because of Cuba embargo and political stuff).
3. Using software methods (This seems the best option for me).

In my research on option 3 I discovered old and ancients ways to unlock it: SAM method, Jailbreaking it and then installing ultrasn0w via Cydya, but this methods seems to not work as I have tried.

So my question is, can I unlock an iPhone 4s (running iOS 6.1.3, but I can upgrade to iOS 9.3.6 (which is the latest firmware by Apple for this device)) for using with whatever carrier I want to? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of research I did find out how to unlock the iPhone and use it with CUBACEL (unique cuban cell company).

To achieve the carrier unlock I just upgraded the old 6.1.3 iOS to the latest 9.3.6 (last IPWS signed by Apple for iPhone 4S) using [3utools](https://www.3u.com/tutorial/articles/8806/everything-you-need-to-know-about-pro-flash-in-3utools#:%7E:text=When%20you%20flash%20your%20iDevice,%E2%80%9CReserve%20baseband%20while%20flashing%E2%80%9D.).

Now I can use my iPhone as a cellphone and not as a glorified brick/mpr3player